# How to separate models in different modules in Django admin's index?

Tags: django, django-admin

I would like to separate my app's models in the admin index:

I registered all my models in `admin.py` and I get all of them in the default admin index under the big red 1 shown below.

Now I'd like to have some of my models in another "block", as shown below under the big red 2.

To make it harder, I also need to have some models in both "blocks", but with different queryset.

How can I do that?

[image]

Comment: You have to create an admin.py on each app. Is that what you mean?

Comment: No. I've got one app with several models, and I'd like to separate the models, as show in the picture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tested my solution and it works.

Do this:

```
class MyModelTest(models.Model):
    # Fields here
    class Meta:
        app_label = 'My other app namespace'
```

---

UPDATE:

To achieve your goal (max flexibility) , you will need to modify the template `admin/app_index.html` and the view `django.contrib.admin.sites.app_index` to your own needs.

Comment: It messes things up (I get some database table errors when trying to modify some items).

Comment: probably because some other model uses it a foreign key?

Comment: Exactly. Moreover, I would also like to have some models in both blocks, with different queryset (I edited my question to add that). I'm not sure I can achieve that with your method.

Comment: after some tests, see my update..I didnt come up with a better solution, sry

Comment: It seems that there is no better solution indeed. Thanks.